# Jquery 1.5 and 1.10 error in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, wordpress

Guys,

I have a little doubt. I'm using WordPress 3.6.1 latest version. Also using Nimble-Portfolio Plugin and I have a Lava Lamp Nav Menu. WordPress automatically include jquery.js?ver=1.10.2. It's fine. But when It's loading my Lava Menu is not working. Lava Lamp menu needed jquery.js?ver=1.5. When I'm loading this in my header. Lava Lamp menu is working fine. Porfolio is not working. What I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try this

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

This will solve your problem hopefully.

Comment: try this when you are loading lava lamp menu on document ready.

Comment: Also check in console if some jquery gets included twice. Sometimes this may also be a cause.

Comment: Yeah! I know. Lava Lamp is not working on Jquery 1.10.2. If I disable it. WordPress not working perfectly

Comment: You are right. Need to update Lavalamp Js file to newer versions